# TeXPad: erroneous alignment in TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, texpad

If I compile the following code on my MacBook Pro (TeXLive 2016), there is no problem at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,3) -- (3,0) node[below] {$\frac{I}{p_x}$};
        \node at (3,3) [draw, text width=7em] {text 1 \\ text 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the same code is used on [TeXPad (iOS version)](https://www.texpadapp.com/), alignment is incorrectly set inside the square box and in the fraction.

[image]

I reported the problem to TeXPad long ago, but no fix yet so far.

Can anyone suggest how to to deal with the problem (e.g. alternative code)?

[A related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315564/texpad-not-showing-tikz-diagrams-correctly)

Here is the output of `\listfiles`.

```
File List*
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tikz.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
pgf.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2015/09/1 Colour configuration of vvtex
vvtex.def    2015/03/01 v1.0
pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
```

Comment: can you write `\pgfversion` somewhere in your document in texpad?

Comment: It says 3.0.1a.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with 'Local Typeset'. I have noticed the same behavior which goes away when you choose 'Cloud Typeset'. I reported the problem.